# Unable to instrument expo app with istanbul or cypress/instrument

Tags: expo, babeljs, cypress, code-coverage, istanbul

I have been trying this for a while now, without success.

I have an expo app and I am using cypress to test some use cases using the web version of the app (generated by expo).

However, I would like to generate some code coverage as well. I have read the [official documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage#Full-stack-code-coverage) for it, that recommends to [`babel-plugin-istanbul`](https://github.com/istanbuljs/babel-plugin-istanbul) do to so, but it does not seem to work with expo.

I am not sure why this would not work.

#### Edit

I removed the files previously pointed here as they were not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for a [wonderful documentation](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/testing-rn-todo-app/) provided by a hero without a cape, I figured that my settings were wrong.

All I needed to do was:

1. install `babel-plugin-istanbul`
2. Update `babel.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  plugins: [
    'istanbul',
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['.'],
        extensions: [
          '.js',
        ],
        alias: {
          '@': './',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

3. update `cypress/support/index.js`

```js
import '@cypress/code-coverage/support';
```

4. update `cypress/plugins/index.js`

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config);

  // add other tasks to be registered here

  // IMPORTANT to return the config object
  // with the any changed environment variables
  return config;
};
```

and voilà!